# SQL Server / SSIS - Exporting a stored procedure to flat file csv preserving carriage return/line feeds

Tags: csv, ssis, sql-server-2012

I need to export a result set from a SQL Server stored procedure to a csv file.  One of the fields being exported is a notes field which can contain quotes and carriage return/line feeds.

I'm using the SSIS data flow task to get the result set from the sproc and then to a flat file destination.

The problem I'm having is how to deal with the carriage return/line feeds.  With the row delimiter being {CR/LF} it starts a new row when it encounters this in the notes field.  I'm viewing the output with the preview when creating the flat file destination.

The database notes fields is datatype NVARCHAR(MAX).

I'm also having the same problem when exporting record details to an SSRS report.  The notes fields are not persisting the carriage return/line feeds resulting in garbled bunch of text.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Been at this for hours.

Thanks

Comment: When you say 'it starts a new row' what exactly do you mean? Look at the contents of the file as written, not the data viewer. Bottom line: if you have row delimiters as part of the data then you probably need to either choose a new row delimiter or escape the delimiters that appear in your notes field.

Comment: How do you want to treat CarrigeReturn and LineFeed: omit or subtitute with anything?

Comment: I would like to preserve the carriage returns and linefeeds,  I've tried wrapping the notes fields in double quotes and replacing any double quotes that already exist in the notes field with single quotes.  I can't seem to get SSIS to do anything properly.

Answer (score 0):

Change field datatype to `text` or `ntext`.

You can also do double substitution:

- Replace CR and LF with 2 unique character combinations in SP
- Replace these char sets with CR and LF in SSIS/SSRS.

Comment: This is going to eliminate the CF/LF which their response indicated they'd like to preserve.